# underline in align environment

Tags: align, underline

A small problem this time: I try to underline my result in an align environment using the package `ulem`. The problem: I want to underline the whole result (e.g. `x=1`) not only 1. But because I like the `= aligned`, I have to write `x&=1`. If I want to underline it, the `&` is inside the `\uuline{}` and it gives an error.

Is there a solution for this? I found a "solution" online, but they put a line below outside and brought it in position via hspace and vspace, and that's a very dirty solution.

Here's an MWE, commented is the line which doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
Here's an example:
\begin{align*}
x+2&=3\\
x&=\uuline{1}
%\uuline{x&=1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May I suggest it would look better boxed? The `mathtools` package (which loads `amsmath`) defines the `\Aboxed{...}` command, which accepts  `&`.

Comment: Shouldn't "not online 1" be "not only 1"? I've omitted this edition, waiting for your decision.

Comment: Yeah, it should be "not only 1", sorry. So in this case your solution given below is perfectly fine, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This underlines the second line of your pair, as required.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
Here's an example:
\begin{align*}
x+2&=3\\
\makebox[0pt][l]{\uuline{\phantom{$x=1$}}}
x&=1
%x&=\uuline{1}
%\uuline{x&=1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to use it many times, writing a macro should decrease the time needed.